# What are the odds for a Pokemon being shiny in Legends: Arceus?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

How does exactly shiny Pokemon work in Legends: Arceus? Are stars/squares shiny variants still present? And what about shiny-locked ones?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard rate remains at the general **1 in 4096**.

There are, however, a few ways to improve this number. You get a first boost at Research Level 10 for the specific Pokémon in the Pokédex. This can be boosted even further if you get the Dex Research Perfect.

And of course the Shiny Charm, which you get

> for getting Research Rank 10 with all 237 non-Mythical Pokémon within the game.

Here's a table to summarize:

| Bonus | Standard rate | Mass Outbreak rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Base | 1 in 4096 | 26 in 4096 1 in 157.5 |
| Species Research Level 10 | 2 in 4096 1 in 2048 | 27 in 4096 1 in 151.7 |
| Species Research Perfect | 4 in 4096 1 in 1024 | 29 in 4096 1 in 141.2 |
| Species Research Level 10 & Shiny Charm | 5 in 4096 1 in 819.2 | 30 in 4096 1 in 136.5 |
| Species Research Perfect & Shiny Charm | 7 in 4096 1 in 585.14 | 32 in 4096 1 in 128 |

Regarding unobtainable ones, all Legendary Pokémon and the starters are shiny-locked, but you can get Shiny Starter Pokémon

> in Space-Time Distortions.

And no more Star and Square Shiny Pokémon, there is only one Shiny animation in this game.

Source, [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/legendsarceus/shinypokemon.shtml).

##### Shiny locked

These Pokemon are unobtainable in their shiny variant:

- Oshawott, Rowlett, and Cyndaquil (the ones you get from Professor Laventon)
- Uxie, Mesprit, and Azelf
- Dialga and Palkia
- Heatran, Regigigas, and Cresselia
- Giratina
- Tornadus, Thundurus, Landorus and Enamorus
- Darkrai
- Shaymin
- Manaphy and Phione
- Arceus

Comment: My friends will be glad to know shiny rates are increased in this game, given the fact I got a day-one shiny and they almost kicked me out

Comment: Outbreaks are great for getting shinies. I managed to get 4 shinies this way, another I lucked out in a space-time distortion.

Comment: It's worth noting that Unown is shiny locked while hunting them throughout the world. When you capture all 28, which allows them to spawn in Solaceon Ruins, they are not shiny locked