# Is there a reason to complete additional research tasks after a Pokédex entry is completed?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

A Pokémon's entry in the Pokédex is considered complete once you reach Research Level 10. However, there are usually several unfinished tasks left after a Pokemon's research is "complete".

Is there a reason to keep completing a Pokémon's research tasks after its Pokédex entry has been completed?

[image: Bibarel Pokédex entry]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple benefits to completing all research tasks.

**Shiny Chances**

By perfecting the research, you get a huge boost to encounter a shiny for that species. The shiny rate becomes a base 1/1024<sup>([Source](https://www.serebii.net/legendsarceus/shinypokemon.shtml))</sup>
 chance for standard encounters rather than 1/4096, along with other factors to further increase it

**Ranking**

As [Joe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/51234/joe) stated in their [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395817/124566), performing the tasks to perfect a Pokémon's research will continue to grant research points to achieve 10 Stars in the Galaxy Team Rank. [Brade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/253677/brade) also mentioned in a comment that simply achieving rank 10 for each Pokémon was not enough to reach 10 stars, so continuing (albeit not necessarily perfecting) these tasks is required to reach max rank.

**Coolness**

As [Pinckerman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/87579/pinckerman) stated in their [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395819/124566), the Pokéball icon that appears next to the Pokémon in the Pokédex turns to a shiny Pokéball.

Comment: Related: [What are the odds for a Pokemon being shiny in Legends: Arceus?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395183/87579).

Comment: I feel a mention of how even Max Points, 99,999, can be achieved without Perfecting every 'Dex entry, as seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-y7OF9mNnAQ
...
I wonder if it's possible to 10 Star without Perfecting any Task nor any Entry...

Comment: @V2Blast Why was the community wiki status removed from this post? I am just now seeing that this action was taken

Answer (score 23):

In addition to Wondercricket's excellent reason, you also continue to get Research points towards your [Pokédex Rank](https://www.serebii.net/legendsarceus/pokedexrank.shtml), which increases your ability to control Pokémon.  Getting to 10 Stars is very difficult (it requires as many points as level 1-9 *combined*) and is much easier to do if you Perfect the easier Pokémon.

Comment: In addition to this, you actually cannot reach 10 stars with just level 10 research on every pokemon. I had gotten level 10 for the whole pokedex and still needed roughly another 5000-6000 points to actually reach 10 stars. So if they are easy, definitely do them!

Answer (score 8):

Following @*Wondercricket*'s answer, the Pokedex itself gives you a hint on what happens completing a "Perfect entry", since the classic Pokeball icon becomes this:

[image: shiny Pokeball]

> The "perfect" icon shows sparkles resembling the animation of a Shiny Pokemon.

Comment: This answer appears incomplete to me. If you don't want to spoil what *actually* happens to the casual reader, then you can write it using the markup for spoilers.

Comment: Actually I was implying you do the opposite: Explain to people what the sparkling of the pokebal actually hints at, but hide that under a spoiler if you believe that knowing so would spoil something.